# SQL Server: select query that creates a timestamp column when a specific column is update to a specific value

Tags: sql, ssms, sql-server-2014

I am reasonably new to SQL and I would like some help to create a SQL Server `SELECT` statement (so I can use this to create a view) which creates a new column with a date/timestamp when a specific column is updated. This is specific to a column change rather than a row change.

The specific column (`PRINT_STATUS`) can either contain 0, 1 or 2. These are always updated in this sequence, eg.0 can be changed to 1 but 2 cannot be changed to 1 etc.

I would like a new column to be updated with a date/time stamp when the column moves from 0 to 1. It's important that this is a permanent date/timestamp - it should only be changed/created once, when it moves from 0 to 1. Many thanks

Comment: I think you need a trigger to implement this functionality.

Comment: Providing the desired results and an example of what you tried already would help people to answer.

Comment: A view cannot store data.you probably need a **trigger** to do this, but you also need to create  a table that will store these *events*

Comment: ok - I have created  a table for this - will then move onto create the trigger.